# Create SQL Server database from existing MySql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, data-migration

I have big MySql database (close to 50 tables), and I want to create same database in SQL Server and later to synchronize data.
Is there a fast way to create sql server database from existing Mysql (to avoid making database from scratch) ?

Comment: does Mysql and SQL are in one machine or they are connected through a network

Comment: 50 tables isn't big in the scheme of things. size, however, in a database isn't measured in "tables" or "columns", or even "rows", it's measured in storage size. Your database could have 1M tables, each with 1M Columns, but if only 1 those tables has any data, and all those columns are a `bit` with the value `1`, then  actually, it's a very small database. :)

Comment: They are connected by network, my biggest issue was to recreate structure of database in SQL server from Mysql

Answer (score 1):

just by googling i found some one is created a project that you want

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a linked server connection from SQL Server to MySQL.

Then you can access the tables directly and load the data into SQL Server.

[Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/) is a tutorial on this subject.